# Minimizing distance between two sets of points given a distortion vector

Tags: r

I have two matching sets of points in 2-dimensional space:

```
template = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                      y = c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5))

source = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                    y = c(4.5,4,3,2,1,1,0))
```

I am planning to fit the `source` into the `template`.

Additionally, I have a distortion vector `magnitude` which is added to the y-value of `source` and determines the amount by which each point is moved in y-direction.

```
magnitude = c(0.5,1,2,3,4,5,5)
```

Now I want to search for a scalar `lambda` that is multiplied to `magnitude` and will altogether minimize the euclidean distance to the `template`:

```
minDist = source[,2] + magnitude *lambda
```

Is there any known algorithm that solves this problem?

I can only think of an iterative approach to approximate `lambda`(insert a random value for `lambda`, compute the distance between `template` and `minDist`, then repeat until threshold is reached).

Example illustration with random value inserted for `lambda`:

```
lambda = 0.95
minDist = source[,2] + magnitude *lambda

plot(template, type = "b", pch = 21, bg = "gray", ylim = c(0,6))
points(source, type = "b", pch = 21, bg = "red")
points(x = 1:7, y = minDist, type = "b", pch = 21, bg = "blue") #fitted points for lambda = 0.95
```

[image]

Comment: Do the `x` values of template and source necessarily match? What is your distance metric? e.g. RMSE of cartesian distance?

Comment: If you are happy with minimizing the sum of the squared distance, then you can use `lm`, as in `lm(template$y - source$y ~ magnitude + 0)`, which gives a coefficient of 0.938. If you want to minimize the sum of the absolute distance you could use `optimize`.

Comment: @JonSpring yes, the x-values do match. I'll add that to my question. I'm looking for the minimum euclidean distance.

Comment: I'd have to write an equation or two to check, but I think if you want to minimize the absolute distance then the answer is `mean((template$y - source$y) / magnitude)`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an estimated approach".

Comment: @GregorThomas I thought that taking the mean would not be ideal necessarily, but actually I think that's exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's what you want.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you kindly. That was much easier than I initially thought. It's time for weekend.